Getting the Value of an Array Select in Form with JQUERY
I have a problem hiding my Admin_Email_Address with the selected value from a form with an array
the array is 0-Activated and 1-Deactivated
What I am trying to do is if I select the 1 from the drop-down the email form is hidden and when 0 it is not hidden and can be inputted
<!-- STATUS --> 
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4">
    <?php $err = isset($_SESSION['sys_employees_edit_status_err']) ? 1 : 0; ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="status" class="mr-1<?php if ($err) { echo ' text-danger'; } ?>"><?php if ($err) { echo '<i class="far fa-times-circle mr-1"></i>'; } echo renderLang($lang_status); ?></label> <span class="right badge badge-success"><?php echo renderLang($label_required); ?></span>
        <select class="form-control required<?php if ($err) { echo ' is-invalid'; } ?>" id="status" name="status" required>
           
           
           <?php
            foreach ($status_arr as $status) {
                echo '<option value="' . $status[0] . '"';
                if (isset($_SESSION['sys_employees_edit_status_val'])) {
                    if ($_SESSION['sys_employees_edit_status_val'] == $status[0]) {
                        echo ' selected';
                    }
                }
                echo '>' . renderLang($status[1]) . '</option>';
            }
            ?>
        </select>
        <?php if ($err) {
            echo '<p class="error-message text-danger mt-1">' . $_SESSION['sys_employees_edit_status_err'] . '</p>';
            unset($_SESSION['sys_employees_edit_status_err']);
        } ?>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- ADMIN EMAL ADDRESS -->
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="admin_email_address" class="mr-1<?php echo $err ? 'text-danger' : ''; ?>"> <?php echo $err ? '<i class="far fa-times-circle mr-1"></i>' : ''; echo "Admin Email Address" ?></label>
        <span class="right badge badge-success"><?php echo renderLang($label_required); ?></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control required<?php echo $err ? ' is-invalid' : ''; ?>" id="admin_email_address" name="admin_email_address" placeholder="" required>
    </div>
</div> 

<script>
        $(".status").keyup(function() {
        if ($('select#status option:selected').val(); = 1 ) {
            $('#admin_email_address').attr('hidden', true);
            
        } else {
            $('#admin_email_address').attr('hidden', false);   
        }
    });

</script>

I tried to so many times to get the value of it but it still doesn't work

You have below issues:
a) .val(); is a syntax issue while doing comparison.
b) = 1 is not a comparison, it's an assignment, so you need to fix it with == 1.
c) There is no HTML attribute hidden exist. You can achieve it via .toggle() or .css() using jQuery
d) Since you want things to happen on change of the select box value then you need .change() not .keyUp()
Here is the solution:
$("#status").change(function() {
  $('#admin_email_address_container').toggle($(this).val() != 1);
});

Sample snippet:


$("#status").change(function() {
  $('#admin_email_address_container').toggle($(this).val() != 1);
});

/* or you can use this code as well
$("#status").change(function() {
  if ($(this).val() == 1) {
    $('#admin_email_address_container').css('display', 'none');
  } else {
    $('#admin_email_address_container').css('display', 'block');
  }
});
*/
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="status">
  <option value="-1">Please select</option>
  <option value="0">Activate Email Address</option>
  <option value="1">Deactivate Email Address</option>
</select>


<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4" id="admin_email_address_container">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="admin_email_address" class="mr-1">Admin email Address</label>
    <span class="right badge badge-success">*</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control required" id="admin_email_address" name="admin_email_address" placeholder="" required>
  </div>
</div>



Note: In case you decided to go with javascript rather than jQuery then also you can use the below code (a modified version of your code)
document.getElementById('status').addEventListener('change', function() {
  document.getElementById('admin_email_address_container').style.display = (this.value == 1) ? 'none' : 'block';
});


I solved it now i just changed the jquery value to change so it is easier
<!-- STATUS -->
                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4">
                                    <?php $err = isset($_SESSION['sys_employees_edit_status_err']) ? 1 : 0; ?>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="status" class="mr-1<?php if ($err) { echo ' text-danger'; } ?>"><?php if ($err) { echo '<i class="far fa-times-circle mr-1"></i>'; } echo renderLang($lang_status); ?></label> <span class="right badge badge-success"><?php echo renderLang($label_required); ?></span>
                                        <select class="form-control required<?php if ($err) { echo ' is-invalid'; } ?>" id="status" name="status" required>
                                            <?php
                                            foreach ($status_arr as $status) {
                                                echo '<option value="' . $status[0] . '"';
                                                if (isset($_SESSION['sys_employees_edit_status_val'])) {
                                                    if ($_SESSION['sys_employees_edit_status_val'] == $status[0]) {
                                                        echo ' selected';
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                echo '>' . renderLang($status[1]) . '</option>';
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        </select>
                                        <?php if ($err) {
                                            echo '<p class="error-message text-danger mt-1">' . $_SESSION['sys_employees_edit_status_err'] . '</p>';
                                            unset($_SESSION['sys_employees_edit_status_err']);
                                        } ?>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <!-- ADMIN EMAIL ADDRESS -->
                                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4" id="admin_email_address_container" style="<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['sys_employees_edit_status_val']) && $_SESSION['sys_employees_edit_status_val'] == 1) ? '' : 'display: none;'; ?>">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="admin_email_address" class="mr-1<?php echo $err ? 'text-danger' : ''; ?>"> <?php echo $err ? '<i class="far fa-times-circle mr-1"></i>' : ''; echo "Admin Email Address" ?></label>
                                        <span class="right badge badge-success"><?php echo renderLang($label_required); ?></span>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control required<?php echo $err ? ' is-invalid' : ''; ?>" id="admin_email_address" name="admin_email_address" placeholder="" required>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <script>
                                    document.getElementById('status').addEventListener('change', function() {
                                        var adminEmailContainer = document.getElementById('admin_email_address_container');
                                        if (this.value == 0) {
                                            adminEmailContainer.style.display = '';
                                        } else {
                                            adminEmailContainer.style.display = 'none';
                                        }
                                    });
                                </script>



explain your answer properly, i.e. what you changed and why (see [answer]. 2) format the code so we can see it without scrolling. Downvotes are happening because you didn't put any effort into writing the answer. You can [edit] it


I would suggest you delete the answer to follow the SO guidelines as well to save yourself from unnecessary down-votes. Also, check the other answer to understand the issues in your code for future perspective as well as to get solutions in javascript/jQuery both.
